# Running shumway locally

Tags: javascript, html, flash, renderer

I found Mozilla's [Shumway](https://mozilla.github.io/shumway/) project a few days ago, it is capable of rendering swf files without the proprietary flash plugin.

I would like to try getting it to work locally as a test so I downloaded the source and basically made a clone of [this](https://mozilla.github.io/shumway/examples/racing/) setup.

I went through each of the viewer files and made sure the links to scripts are all correct for my local implementation, however it does not display the viewer.

What is it that I'm missing?

I can provide a copy of my implementation if needed somewhere, but not sure where to upload it.